# All measure columns in analyses suddenly showing null in OBIEE

Tags: oracle, obiee

Very strange thing has happened in our OBIEE. There were no modifications in rpd or in database, but every analyses that contains measure column has null values for that column. In all of them.

Here is one example that has been working fine till now.
Criteria:
[image]

Corresponding Result:

[image]

Checked a physical query generated for this simple analyses and it is different:

```
WITH SAWITH0 AS
 (select distinct T5520.CAL_DAY as c1, T3160.CODE as c2
    from DM_FILIALS_V   T3160 /* D04 Filials */,
         DM_CALENDAR_V  T5520 /* D03 Calendar */,
         DM_FACT_DATA_V T74769 /* F44 Dm Fact Data */
   where (T3160.CODE = T74769.FILIAL_CODE and T5520.CAL_DAY = T74769.PERIOD and
         T5520.CAL_DAY = TO_DATE('2021-06-11', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and
         T74769.PERIOD = TO_DATE('2021-06-11', 'YYYY-MM-DD')))
select D1.c1 as c1,
       D1.c2 as c2,
       D1.c3 as c3,
       D1.c4 as c4,
       D1.c5 as c5,
       D1.c6 as c6
  from (select D1.c1 as c1,
               D1.c2 as c2,
               D1.c3 as c3,
               D1.c4 as c4,
               D1.c5 as c5,
               D1.c6 as c6
          from (select 0 as c1,
                       D1.c1 as c2,
                       D1.c2 as c3,
                       cast(NULL as DOUBLE PRECISION) as c4,
                       cast(NULL as DOUBLE PRECISION) as c5,
                       cast(NULL as DOUBLE PRECISION) as c6,
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY D1.c1, D1.c2 ORDER BY D1.c1 ASC, D1.c2 ASC) as c7
                  from SAWITH0 D1) D1
         where (D1.c7 = 1)
         order by c2, c3) D1
 where rownum <= 10000000
```

Can anybody tell what is going on here? I tried to restart BI services from EM, but that didn't help.

Comment: It's not possible that this appeared automagically without any change. What was done? Was there a patch? A deployment?

Comment: Yes, @Chris, it appears there was a change in rpd a day before this happened. It was just reported later tomorrow during which no change was made. 
Uploading rpd version without these changes fixed the issue.

Comment: However, it is still strange that this happened. The change was to a fact table that is completely irrelevant to other fact tables or the one show in the question. There was a fact table in rpd, but after design modifications it was decided to change it to dimension since now it behaved like one. In short, fact table was redesigned as dimension, irrelevant joins were removed. Uploading this rpd caused problem with fact tables showing null values everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the underlying model isn't valid you will always run into issues. It isn't "strange" since basically you modeled something which - to the model - implied that the fact had no valid relationship with the dimension. I.e. that the fact can't be analyzed by that dimension. Think in terms of conformed and non-conformed dimensions. Yours had become a non-conformed dimension.

Never forget that logically you model "relationships", not technical "joins".